# Pass a set of xml values to an object using Linq in c#

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

Created a class to help pass values from an xml:

```
class ApptDetails
{
    // public string date { get; set; }
    public string starttime { get; set; }
    public string endtime { get; set; }
    public string details { get; set; }
    public string notes { get; set; }
}
```

Using this XML format:

```
<March>
    <date>
    03/09/2024
    <starttime>8:00 AM</starttime>
        <endtime>8:30 AM</endtime>
        <details>blah1</details>
        <notes>blarty1</notes>
    </date>
    <date>
    03/09/2024
    <starttime>9:00 AM</starttime>
        <endtime>9:30 AM</endtime>
        <details>blah2</details>
        <notes>blarty2</notes>
    </date>
    <date>
    03/09/2024
    <starttime>10:00 AM</starttime>
        <endtime>10:30 AM</endtime>
        <details>it finally freakin works!!!!</details>
        <notes>Can i get an AMEN?</notes>
    </date>
</March>
```

I couldn't even begin to describe all the things I have tried here. I have been researching this for over a week now, and have tried over a dozen different approaches. This is where I am at now, and is a bit of a culmination of what I have learned so far. Right now I am just sending the class variables to a messagebox for testing. The issue is the values are not passing to the object.

```
if (File.Exists(@"C:\FSAppointmentsTest\Appointments\" + now.ToString("MMMM") + ".xml"))
{
    ApptDetails apptDetails = new ApptDetails();

    XDocument appointments = XDocument.Load(@"C:\FSAppointmentsTest\Appointments\" +       now.ToString("MMMM") + ".xml");

    foreach (var child in appointments.Descendants("starttime"))
    {
        // XDocument appointmentData = XDocument.Parse("date");
        IEnumerable<ApptDetails> result = from date in appointments.Descendants("starttime")
                                          select new ApptDetails()
                                              {
                                                  starttime =       (string)date.Attribute("starttime").Value.ToString(),
                                                  endtime =     (string)date.Attribute("endtime").Value.ToString(),
                                                  details = (string)date.Attribute("details").Value.ToString(),
                                                  notes = (string)date.Attribute("notes").Value.ToString(),
                                              };

        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(apptDetails.starttime);
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(apptDetails.endtime);
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(apptDetails.details);
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(apptDetails.notes);
    }
}
```

Apologies if I missed anything. I have been reading from here for a long time but it is my first actual plea for help.

Comment: 1. you probably meant `appointments.Descendants("date")` - 2. starttime, endtime etc. are not attributes, but elements,

Comment: @KlausGütter Not sure what you mean? Am I using the wrong verbiage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp10
{
    class ApptDetails
    {
        public DateTime date { get; set; }
        public DateTime starttime { get; set; }
        public DateTime endtime { get; set; }
        public string details { get; set; }
        public string notes { get; set; }

        public ApptDetails(XElement element)
        {
            date = DateTime.Parse(element.FirstNode.ToString());
            starttime = (DateTime)element.Element("starttime");
            endtime = (DateTime)element.Element("starttime");
            details = (string)element.Element("details");
            notes = (string)element.Element("notes");

        }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
         static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            List<ApptDetails> details = doc.Descendants("date").Select(x => new ApptDetails(x)).ToList();
  

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: This creates the list perfectly, but its not allowing me to reference specific elements. I understood this should work like "details.date" for the messagebox value? Error message is: error CS1061: 'List<Form3.ApptDetails>' does not contain a definition for 'starttime' and no accessible extension method 'starttime' accepting a first argument of type 'List<Form3.ApptDetails>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: You are not using the correct instance of details.  For some reason your form isn't finding the correct instance of details.  Are you using my class ApptDetails or your original class?  Your class had starttime commented out.

Comment: I changed it over to yours. I didnt think i needed my version anymore?

Comment: It looks like you are trying to send an object to a Form.  So one way is to add object as a parameter to the constructor : Form3 form3 = new Form3(details).  See my two form project at following : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34975508/reach-control-from-another-page-asp-net

Comment: It looks like you're right. Have no clue why though i made a string for the document load path, load the doc, create details using the list as you wrote it, and try to print the value to messagebox., or refer to an element for a foreach loop.

Comment: Also, im not using 2 forms, This is part of the form3_load. Is that why its showing as form3 ApptDetails?

Comment: Than you have a Console Application loading a Form which opens the form using the constructor.  Anytime you open a Form with a constructor you can pass parameters like a list of classes in my link.

Comment: Where is the Form3 Load?

Comment: its a winform project so instead of public void main it has form_load

Comment: public partial class Form3 : Form
{
    public Form3()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form3_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
        string monthDoc = @"C:\FSAppointmentsTest\Appointments\" + now.ToString("MMMM") + ".xml";
        dayName1.Text = now.ToString("dddd MMMM dd, yyyy");
        XDocument appointments = XDocument.Load(monthDoc);
        List<ApptDetails> details = appointments.Descendants("date").Select(x => new ApptDetails(x)).ToList();

Comment: Solution is to move the class ApptDetails so it is outside program class.  I modified my code above.

Comment: details is a list so should be : details.Select(x => x.date)

Comment: Looks like that worked! Appreciate your time